# asp.net angularjs how to click on link and route to controller method with Id

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am writing a View which binds the angularjs scope object with the View. 
I have a 'Read More' link with ng-href which reference a URL but I need
to change it to call a specific controller method with a Guid Id.

I have this so far

```
<span><a ng-href="{{item.url}}">Read More</a></span>
```

how do I change it to call a specific Controller method with the Id like item.Id?

Thanks for any help

```
 <div class="table-responsive" news-listing>
                <table style="width: 100%;" style="border-collapse: separate;">
                    <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid black; padding-top: 25px;padding-bottom: 25px;" ng-repeat="item in listItems">
                        <td colspan="100%"></td>
                        <td>
                            <img ng-src="{{item.thumbnail}}" style="width: 100px; height: 75px"/>
                        </td>
                        <td style="padding-left: 25px;">
                            <div small>

                                <span ng-bind="item.publishedDateFormated" style="font-weight: bold"></span>
                                <span style="font-weight: bold"> | </span>
                                <span ng-bind="item.headline" style="font-weight: bold"></span><br/>
                                <span ng-bind="item.teaser"></span><br/>
                                <span><a ng-href="{{item.url}}">Read More</a></span>

                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-click`.

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" ng-click="readMore(item.id)">Read More</a>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$scope.readMore = function(itemId) {
    //do things here
    openModal();
    alert("hello world!");

    //go to a new url perhaps?
    window.location = "path/to/stuff?itemId=" + itemId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To call the controller method you don't use `href` instead you use `ngClick` like:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="yourMethodName()">Read More</a>
```

Comment: How do you route to the MVC controller that is the c# code?